# Firebase security rules getting a value from another node and comparing it with auth.uid

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am having difficulties with setting up the Firebase security rules by taking the value of another node and comparing it with `auth.uid`

My structure is as follows:

```
/$environment
/$environment/data/$client_id
/$environment/users/$uid/client_id
```

I would like to make sure that the authenticated user with `auth.uid` can only view the data at `$client_id` if `$uid/client_id` is equivalent.

I tried the following but in the simulator it says access denied:

```
{
  /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
  "rules": {
    ".write": false,
    "$environment": {

      /* Data */
      "data": {
        "$client_id": {
            ".read": "$client_id === root.child($environment+'/users/'+auth.uid+'/client_id').val()"
        }
      },

      /* Account settings */
      "users": {
        "$uid": {
          ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
        }
      }

    /* --------------------------------*/
    /* end environment, rules and json */
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're missing a `/` before `users` in `root.child($environment+'users/'...`.

Comment: Corrected. Still not working

Comment: Can you update your question to include the actual (relevant) JSON (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). Also please provide the code of a read operation that is failing against that JSON/rules. Also: since you're testing in the simulator, a screenshot containing the relevant details would also go a long way.

Comment: any luck @JohnAndrews?

Comment: Yes it works now, will post my solution soon

Comment: @JohnAndrews You... never posted your solution... which I hope you know by now is a massive sin on StackOverflow...